# How to install a gem globally without sudo using rbenv?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sudo, rbenv

I am using `rbenv` and I am trying to install `sass` without success.

So, I installed `rbenv` via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh), then Ruby 2.2 (`rbenv install 2.2`) and finally `gem install sass`, but I was unable to make `sass` available on my `$PATH`.

Short on time, I `sudo gem install sass` using my system's (Yosemite) default Ruby 2. This put everything in `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0` and things do work, but not in the most desireable way.

Ideally, using `rbenv` I should be able to install any Ruby version and have gems installed inside that version's directory and later symlinked to `/usrl/local/bin`.

Any help as to what could have gone wrong would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question title if you believe the answer below answers your intended question. The title is not commensurate with the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, the problem was I did not add `rbenv/bin/rbenv` to `$PATH`.

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
```

Better yet, add this to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` to start every session with `rbenv`.

After that, make sure to:

```
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

In order to enable shims and autocompletion.

#### fishshell

For those using fish, you can accomplish the same like this:

```
if status --is-interactive
  . (rbenv init - | psub)
end
```

Now, if you don't like modifying `$PATH` directly and have ownership over `/usr/local/bin`, a more nifty solution is to symlink with `~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv`.

```
 ln -s ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv /usr/local/bin
```

#### ruby-build

As a final warning, make sure to install [`ruby-build`](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) (a `rbenv` plugin to add the `install` command to `rbenv` and be able to easily install Ruby versions.)

If you are using [homebrew](http://brew.sh) it's easy as pie:

```
brew install ruby-build
```

Comment: Either the question title is wrong, or this "answer" does not address the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible option that may be of relevance for some here, depending on how one thinks about something being "globally" installed, is — assuming one is using the `rbenv`-based version of the `gem` command — to use the `--user-install` option to `gem install`.  E.g.:

```
gem install --user-install sass
```

This will install things only for the user running it (so not global in that sense), but also in a way where it's not just available to a particular `bundle`-based install, say (so it *is* global in that sense).